# Can't log in to my chromebook forgot the password

Tags: windows-7

My chrome book won't let me enter it because I need to answer an old password and I can't remember it

Comment: Is this a chromebook you own, or one owned by a organization such as your school or employer? Is the account your own personal Google account, or one belonging to an organization?

Answer (score 1):

The article
[Fix sign-in problems](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/6375270?hl=en)
suggests various fixes, most centered around logging-in to your account on
http://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery.

If this also fails, see the article
[Find your Chromebook's owner account](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1059256?hl=en),
where the last resort is:

> 1. [Reset your Chromebook to factory settings](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183084). This
>    process will erase all data, files, and accounts on your Chromebook.
> 2. [Set up your Chromebook](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1047362)
>    again and sign in with the account that you want as the owner.